# Query demora para ser finalizada

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Boa tarde Pessoal, 
estou com um problema ao executar uma query no c# usando o NPGSQL.

```
            try
            {
                bdConn.Open();

                NpgsqlCommand sql = new NpgsqlCommand();
                sql.Connection = bdConn;
                sql.CommandText = query;
                sql.CommandTimeout = 600000;
                NpgsqlDataReader dr = sql.ExecuteReader();                    

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string xml = dr[1].ToString();
                    xml = xml.Replace("<![CDATA[", "").Replace("]]>", "");

                    switch (cbbDocumento.Text)
                    {
                        case "NFe": System.IO.File.WriteAllText(tbPasta.Text + "\\" + dr[0].ToString() + "-nfe.xml", xml); break;
                        case "NFCe": System.IO.File.WriteAllText(tbPasta.Text + "\\" + dr[0].ToString() + "-nfce.xml", xml); break;
                        case "CTe": System.IO.File.WriteAllText(tbPasta.Text + "\\" + dr[0].ToString() + "-cte.xml", xml); break;
                        case "MDFe": System.IO.File.WriteAllText(tbPasta.Text + "\\" + dr[0].ToString() + "-mdfe.xml", xml); break;
                    }
                }
            }

            finally
            {
                bdConn.Close();

            }
```

Nesse trecho, após o ExecuteReader a conexão continua aberto, e enquanto existirem registros para serem lidos a query continua sendo executada no banco.

Isso acaba consumindo muito processamento do meu servidor de banco de dados.

Existe alguma forma de executar uma query e já fechar essa conexão antes de começar a trabalhar com os dados retornados?

Grato.

Atualização: 
O resultado dessa query tem mais ou menos 80 mil registros e eu salvo o resultado em um local físico.
O problema é que demora mais ou menos 30 minutos para salvar essa quantidade de registros e isso está "matando" o servidor de banco de dados.

Comment: Não dá para ver o que está fazendo. Dá para fechar, você fez isso? Mas não vai mudar nada. O `Datareader` costuma ser a forma mais rápida, o problema parece estar na forma que está fazendo. Ou a *query* é ruim, ou só tem dados demais mesmo. Você precisaria colocar informações que dê subsídio pra gente avaliar, na forma atual a pergunta não está clara, ou não pode ser reproduzida.

Comment: Mas o DataReader.Read() usa ainda usa uma conexão com o banco? Ou apenas interpreta o resultado da query que foi executada no ExecuteReader() ?

Comment: Ainda usa a conexão, mas isso não quer dizer nada. Você está focando em algo que não é o problema.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta agora. Veja se consegue me ajudar.

Comment: Talvez o custo maior é gravar todos esses arquivos

Comment: Você pode ler e "salvar" todo o dataReader para uma list ou algo semelhante e fechar a conexão, e depois trabalhar a parte da escrita dos arquivos com com essa variável auxiliar. Não sei o quanto irá melhorar a performance, ou se irá atrapalhar ainda mais, mas talvez valha o teste.

Comment: Traga todos os dados que quer processar em memória, fechar a conexão e processe com Parallel.For para otimizar a gravação, da forma que está vc atinge o tempo do timeout gerando exception.